# Get the values from another tab and bind the dropdown using signalR

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr

I need to re-bind my drop down with the values from another browser tab. 
ie, Once i click Save button in my one tab it has to bind the dropdown of another tab by using SignalR. Is it possible?

Please advice me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's say you have Browser Tab A and Browser Tab B.  You want values from Tab A to appear in Tab B when Tab A's save button is clicked, yes?

To do this, be sure Tab B is subscribed to a group on the SignalR hub.  Wire up the Save button on Tab A to call a method on the SignalR Hub when clicked.  This method should send the values to subscribers of the group that Tab B is subscribed to.  The values themselves should either be passed into the Hub method, or uploaded elsewhere for Tab B to pull via an Ajax request once it knows it has received the right kind of update from the Hub.